# Упадет ли приложение, если устройство не поддерживает какой-то из permission request?

Tags: android

Такой вопрос:
В приложении есть звонилка. Сможет ли поставиться приложжение из play market(или с apk-файла) на устройство, которое не поддерживает звонки? Или же оно поставиться и упадет при запуске?

P.S. Есть ли симулятор в студи, который не поддерживает звонки, т.е. без симки?

Comment: Упадет. Но вы можете проверять через условие if permission granted делаем или другое. Или от лавливать ексептион через try catch Ps эмулятор любой планшет начиная с Nexus 7.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашел планшет без симки, запустил и оно действительно упало. Нашел вот такой метод, для проверки усть ли у устройства аппаратная поддержка "звонить" (наличие симкарты):

```
private static boolean isCallingSupported(Context context) {

    boolean result = true;
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:12345678912"));
    List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    if (infos.size() <= 0) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Не совсем чистый метод (из-за cтрокового номера), но рабочий.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от версии SDK где запущено и с каким собрано:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous-permission-prompt
Начиная с версии 23 надо обкладывать дополнительными вызовами или использовать AppCompat.

Для эмуляции входящего звонка на эмуляторе можно сделать:

```
 adb -s <serialno> shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:555-5555
```

Comment: извините, ваш ответ как всегда о чем-то не том..